# md-toolbar does not render as a component

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have created a directive for showing the toolbar and it's content:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'ved-toolbar',
    templateUrl: './ved.toolbar.html'
})
export class VedToolbar {

time: Date;

constructor() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.time = new Date();
    }, 1000);
}
}
```

template:

```
<md-toolbar flex="50" color="primary">
<md-toolbar-row>
    <bootstrap-grid>

        <row style="margin: 0;">
            <column md="1"></column>
            <column md="11">
                <column md="4">
                    <span>LOGO Creditas</span>
                </column>
                <span>Prihlaseny pouzivatel</span>
                <column md="4">
                    <span>{{ time | date: 'HH:mm:ss' }}</span>
                </column>
                <column md="4">
                    <span><a routerLink="/doc/detail" routerLinkActive="active">Nápoveda</a></span>
                </column>
            </column>
        </row>
    </bootstrap-grid>

</md-toolbar-row>
```

however, when I use it just like `<ved-toolbar></ved-toolbar>` in `<head></head>` It renders just an empty tag, so nothing is shown.
[image]

If I place it inside `md-sidenav-container` it renders but styles are applied wrong, so it's not fixed on top.

However, when I place ved-toolbar's content into `<head/>` it renders well.

Surely I have added `VedToolbar` into app's module `declarations` list.

What is going wrong in here, please?